# Remove dead leg in cold water pipe or ok (legionella risk)?

Tags: copper-pipe

A while back (there is a post here somewhere but couldn't find it) I had a water leak in my garage. I found the leak and fixed it by placing a cap and bypass that section of pipe (see pictures). I was reading some older post [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/what-temperature-should-i-set-my-water-heater-to) and [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221057/dead-end-in-pipes-and-legionella-risk). One talks about stagnant water in dead legs (quoted below) and I remember the cap I place in the pipe when I fixed it. The other post says it shouldn't matter. I'm concerned. The plan back then was to remove the dead leg, cap and T and replace them with a right angle fitting. I got lazy and left it like that and closed the wall. Should I just fix it right now that I have the time? BTW my pipe is the cold supply but being in the garage it gets warm in the summer ... like now. That supply goes to the kitchen (including the ice maker). I have no water filters anywhere. My water comes from .. the water company, not a well. My place is upstairs so that pipe is almost the lowes point. I'm in California. Thanks.

--------------- Quote from old post begins -------------------

Dead legs

Dead legs (branches that are capped off or rarely used) contain stagnant water that can be an ideal breeding ground for bacteria which can contaminate the entire system. This should not be surprising as the water in the dead leg would get warm, but never hot to the temperature of the main flow.

--------------- Quote from old post ends -------------------

[image: Before Repair]
[image: After Repair]